# Дано натуральное число п. Определить количество различных цифр в нем

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Дано натуральное число п. Определить количество различных цифр в нем
Направьте меня на верный путь )
P.s строки использовать нельзя

```
let num = 4564765;
    mas = [];
while (num) {
    mas.push(num % 10);
    num = Math.floor(num/10);
}
console.log(mas.reverse().join(','));
let count = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < mas.length-1; i++) {
    if(mas[0]==mas[i]) {
        i++;
    }
    else{
        count++;
    }
}
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно, например, схитрить. Превращаем число в строку. Строка поддерживает итерацию, поэтому её легко превратить в Set из уникальных цифр. Останется только получить размер этого Set.

```js
console.log(new Set(String(4564765)).size);
```

Если строки нельзя, тогда так:

```js
let num = 4564765;
const set = new Set();

while (num) {
  set.add(num % 10);
  num = Math.floor(num / 10);
}

console.log(set.size);
```

Comment: можно конечно, но мне строки нельзя использовать )

Comment: @noname Это стоит добавить в вопрос.

Comment: да, хорошо, спасибо

Comment: @noname Добавил вариант без строк.

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @noname, бред, что нельзя использовать строку. Натуральное число - кол-во предметов, кучка шариков, например. Представление этой кучки на письме зависит от системы счисления и способов представления на письме, это и есть строка в конечном счете. Строчное символьное представление кучки шариков.

Comment: Да да, ну что я могу сделать, если такое условие поставил препод, ох уж этот универ...

Comment: Что поделать? Выйти и при всей аудитории объяснить преподу что к чему. Вы же просто ищете повторяющиеся символы, а само число в памяти представлено вообще двоичным кодом, и там нет ни четверок, ни пятерок. А если число в 16-ричной системе счисления, то делить на 16 надо будет? Для одного и того же числа разный результат получится? Полный бред. Это и есть символы, и надо найти количество уникальных символов представления натурального числа на письме. И это ваша отсебятина на счет строк, скорее всего.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function countDifferentDigits(x) {
  var c = Array(10).fill(0)
  do c[x%10] = 1; while (x = x / 10 | 0)
  return c.reduce((r, x) => r + x)
}

console.log(countDifferentDigits(4564765))
console.log(countDifferentDigits(0))
console.log(countDifferentDigits(1))
console.log(countDifferentDigits(10))
console.log(countDifferentDigits(11))
console.log(countDifferentDigits(987987996))
```